# LinkedList Merging of two sorted Arrays

Tags: nullpointerexception

Why my code showing `null pointer exception`?

```
static SinglyLinkedListNode mergeLists(SinglyLinkedListNode head1, SinglyLinkedListNode head2) {
        
        SinglyLinkedListNode node=null;
        SinglyLinkedListNode curr=node;
        
        while(head1!=null && head2!=null){
            if(head1.data>head2.data){
                SinglyLinkedListNode temp=new SinglyLinkedListNode(head2.data);
                head2=head2.next;
                node=temp;
                node=node.next;
                
            }else{
              SinglyLinkedListNode temp=new SinglyLinkedListNode(head1.data);
              head1=head1.next;
              node=temp;
              node=node.next;
            }
        }
        if(head1!=null){
            node=head1;
        }else{
            node=head2;
        }
        return curr;
    }
```

Comment: Which arguments have been passed?

Comment: list1= 1 2 3,    list2=3 4  output should be= 1 2 3 3 4

Comment: How is `SinglyLinkedListNode` defined?